# how to change frequency ( pitch) and the amplitude in wave file using c#

Tags: c#, audio, frequency, naudio, amplitude

how to change frequency (pitch) and the amplitude in wave file using c# like this but on wave file not tone 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tumpkl-xJuA

Comment: Sound is a very complex subject and your question is very broad.  You probably need to start by trying to read a wave file into memory and break it out into the different chunks that define a wave file.  To change the amplitude you'll just multiply each sample by a scale value.  Pitch is a **very** advanced thing to change without changing other factors, so good luck finding anything on that without running into a patent.

Comment: no i want to do the same thing this guy do in video but on wave file not tone

Comment: *pitch amplitude*? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11162668/507950) provides all you need to read a wave (.wav) audio file into a c# array. It normalises the values from -1.0 to 1.0.

So all you need to do is

- Use the above code to read the file into a c# double array. It actually returns two arrays, one for the left and right stereo channels. Just uses one if its mono though.
- Make the modifications to the c# array in memory:

  - Changing pitch means resampling the array at a lower or higher sample rate, in effect stretching or shrinking the waveform to adjust the frequency. You may need to use some form of interpolation at this point.
  - Amplitude adjustment can be done at the next step.
- Write out the array into a new Wave file; refer to https://web.archive.org/web/20141213140451/https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ for full Wave format specification ... its not that complex.