# Processing 16bit sample audio

Tags: c#, audio, fft

Right now i have an audio file (2 Channels, 44.1kHz Sample Rate, 16bit Sample size, WAV) I would like to pass it into this method but i am not sure of any way to convert the WAV file to a byte array.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Process 16 bit sample
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wave"></param>
    public void Process(ref byte[] wave)
    {
        _waveLeft = new double[wave.Length / 4];
        _waveRight = new double[wave.Length / 4];

        if (_isTest == false)
        {
            // Split out channels from sample
            int h = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < wave.Length; i += 4)
            {
                _waveLeft[h] = (double)BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, i);
                _waveRight[h] = (double)BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, i + 2);
                h++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate artificial sample for testing
            _signalGenerator = new SignalGenerator();
            _signalGenerator.SetWaveform("Sine");
            _signalGenerator.SetSamplingRate(44100);
            _signalGenerator.SetSamples(16384);
            _signalGenerator.SetFrequency(5000);
            _signalGenerator.SetAmplitude(32768);
            _waveLeft = _signalGenerator.GenerateSignal();
            _waveRight = _signalGenerator.GenerateSignal();
        }

        // Generate frequency domain data in decibels
        _fftLeft = FourierTransform.FFTDb(ref _waveLeft);
        _fftRight = FourierTransform.FFTDb(ref _waveRight);
    }
```

**Edit** Hi sorry for the confusion. I'm currently new to audio signalling so my explanation of what I might like to get is wrong. For this method to work correctly, i believe i need to pass in the byte array of the data chunk in the wav file only. The end result would be to apply fft on it as shown in the code and transform it to a spectrogram. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754111/how-to-read-the-data-in-a-wav-file-to-an-array

Comment: Hi thanks for the ref. I took a look at it and found out that I'm suppose to only retrieve the byte array that contains the data chunk. On the side note, the example gave a return of a double. How would I change it to a byte array to pass it into my method here. Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Comment: try libsoundfile or one of the many online refs that explain how to read the data from a wav file.

Answer (score 0):

you need:

```
using System.IO;
```

and this code to get the byte array

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(PathToFile);
```

where `PathToFile` is the Location (as String) of the `.wav` file.

Edit:

> Right now i have an audio file (2 Channels, 44.1kHz Sample Rate, 16bit Sample size, WAV) I would like to pass it into this method but i am not sure of any way to convert the WAV file to a byte array.

He asks for a function to get the byte array from the .wav file he didn't say anything about getting the specific part of the byte array that contains the data of the music.
So Downvoting a correct answer is..

Comment: This will read complete file, with RIFF header and stuff. I think the question was about processing audio data from a WAV file.

Comment: Sorry but he asked how to convert the .wav file to a byte array. And not how to get the DataChunk...

Comment: Sry for the confusion. I up voted ur answer as the example u gave was what I "initially" wanted to ask.