# Listen to wav file C#

Tags: c#, audio

What I am wanting to do is have my program listen to a wav file that consists of highs and low and be able to determine what one is what

(basically converting the highs and lows in the wav files to 1's and 0's)

After some googling I haven't found anything that would be able to listen to an audio source or wav file directly to do this so I am currently stumped on what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to take a look at the [NAudio library](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) which allow you to read a WAV file very easily.

Then you will probably need to detect the "highs and lows" yourself by analysing the databytes extracted from your WAV file and create the output file you are looking for also with NAudio (this is basically analysing and filling byte arrays).

This is a usefull article that can help you to understand how to do this :
[Audio Formats - Mark Heath](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET)
And some other threads directly on stack : [How to read the data in a wav file to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754111/how-to-read-the-data-in-a-wav-file-to-an-array)