# Using Assert in NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am using this section of code in my C# program which I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754111/how-to-read-the-data-in-a-wav-file-to-an-array) stackoverflow thread.

```
using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader("myfile.wav"))
{
    Assert.AreEqual(16, reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, "Only works with 16 bit audio");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
    int read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    short[] sampleBuffer = new short[read / 2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, sampleBuffer, 0, read);
}
```

The code uses NAudio, so I have referenced the libary and added `using NAudio.Wave;` but I am receiving the error: The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context.

How can i fix this?

*This may have been better as a comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert is a function from XUnit.

Add that reference. And add the using directive.

`using Xunit;`

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the above error, but now it says 'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'AreEqual'. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: Just delete the line it is not significant for the functionality

Comment: Xunit uses Equal to compare expected and actual value. AreEqual is used by MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

The `Assert.AreEqual` in that code is from NUnit, but taking a dependency on a unit testing framework is completely unnecessary in production code. If you want the check, just throw some kind of exception if it doesn't match. For example:

```
if (reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample != 16)
    throw new NotSupportedException("Only works with 16 bit audio");
```